# NULL values breaking search

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following WHERE statement within a query, but if the DateOfBirth is NULL, it doesn't return a result for a record(s). I can't seem to figure this out and wondering if someone could see the reason?

```
WHERE
    (
        EXISTS( -- if we have words
                SELECT *
                FROM #SearchWords s
                WHERE 
                    ((@SearchType = 'FirstName' OR @SearchType = 'ALL') AND c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%'))
                    OR ((@SearchType = 'LastName' OR @SearchType = 'ALL') AND c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
                    OR ((@SearchType = 'PreferredName' OR @SearchType = 'ALL') AND c.PreferredName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
                    OR ((@SearchType = 'Password' OR @SearchType = 'ALL') AND c.Password LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
                    OR ((@SearchType = 'IdentifierValue' OR @SearchType = 'ALL') AND CI.IdentifierValue LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
            )
        OR @SearchWordCount = 0 --if we don't have words
    )
    AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)
```

Comment: Can `@LowerDate` and `@UpperDate` be `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do use an `OR` expression:

```
AND
(DateOfBirth IS NULL OR
 DateOfBirth BETWEEN COALESCE(@LowerDate, DateOfBirth) AND COALESCE(@UpperDate, DateOfBirth)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That where can be shortened

```
WHERE 
       (     @SearchType in ('FirstName', 'ALL') 
         AND c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%') )
    OR (     @SearchType in ('LastName', 'ALL') 
         AND c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%') )
    OR (     @SearchType in ('PreferredName', 'ALL')  
         AND c.PreferredName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%') )
    OR (     @SearchType in ('Password', 'ALL') 
         AND c.Password LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
    OR (     @SearchType in ('IdentifierValue', 'ALL')  
         AND CI.IdentifierValue LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
```

Comment: Interesting as a comment, but unrelated to the OP's question regarding the query failing to return results when `DateOfBirth` is `NULL`.